# Specify path to tslint package correctly

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine

I have an angular application whose components were generated usng angular CLI: ng g c XXX with a spec.ts file. After I completed the project, I wanted to write some testing files, however, when I opened spec.ts file, it says "please specify path to tslint correctly" do you know whats wrong with it?

I guess it might be because I moved my project to another folder on my desktop? After I clicking on tslint settings, I found the tspackage path is another folder, should I change the path to my current folder?

Comment: what exactly gives that message? The test runner, the CLI, or your editor?

Comment: my editor, I guess it might be because I moved my project to another folder on my desktop?

Answer (score 5):

You must point it to your `node_modules/tslint` in the settings of your "editor".

Answer (score 5):

Got to WebStorm settings `File -> Settings`

Check your path to TSLint package, it should go to `project_dir/node_modules/tslint`

[image]

Comment: Reference : https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/using-tslint-code-quality-tool.html